# Swapping element between the arrays - java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to swap the elements between the array.

```
Array1 = {1,3,-5,4,2,-8}
Array2 = {2,4,7,8,-9}
Array3 = {1,2,3,-4,6}
```

Array1 must contain only the odd values. Array2 has some odd values{7,-9} that should be swapped with the even elements in Array1.
The odd values in the Array2 exhausted then Array3 should be used.

```
public static int readInput(){
    int input = 0;
    // create Scanner object
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String option = scanner.nextLine();
    if (isNumber(option)) {
        input =  Integer.parseInt(option);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops Something went wrong!!");
        extractLargestAndSmallest();
    }
    return  input;
}

public static  void extractLargestAndSmallest(){
    try{
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        System.out.println("How many arrays of int (treating these as array of arrays of int?) ");
        int numberOfArrays = readInput();


        System.out.println("Enter the Array size : ");          
        int number1 = readInput();  
        int numbers1[] = new int[number1];

        // prompt user 
        System.out.print("Enter the array element values: \n");
        // use for loop to obtain user input
        for (int counter = 0; counter < number1; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the value for element at index " +counter);
            numbers1[counter] = readInput();
        }

        System.out.println("Building the Second array --");
        System.out.println("Enter the  Array size :");
        int number2 = readInput(); 
        int numbers2[] = new int[number2];


        System.out.print("Enter the array element values: \n");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < number2; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the value for element at index " +counter);
            numbers2[counter] = readInput();
        }

        System.out.println("Building the Third array --");
        System.out.println("Enter the  Array size :");
        int number3 = readInput(); 
        int numbers3[] = new int[number3];


        System.out.print("Enter the array element values: \n");
        for (int counter = 0; counter < number3; counter++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the value for element at index " +counter);
            numbers3[counter] = readInput();
        }

        System.out.println("Confirming before working through with swapping --");
        System.out.println("There is/are"+ numberOfArrays +"array(s).");

        System.out.println("The current array of index #0 has"+ number1 +"element(s)." );
        for(int i = 0; i< numbers1.length;i++){
            if(numbers1[i]!=0){
                System.out.println(numbers1[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The current array of index #0 has"+ number2 +"element(s)." );
        for(int i = 0; i< numbers2.length;i++){
            if(numbers2[i]!=0){
                System.out.println(numbers2[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The current array of index #0 has"+ number3 +"element(s)." );
        for(int i = 0; i< numbers3.length;i++){
            if(numbers3[i]!=0){
                System.out.println(numbers3[i]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers1.length; i++) {
            if ((numbers1[i]) / 2 == 0) {
                int eventemp[] = new int[] {};
                eventemp[j] = numbers1[i];
                numbers1[i] = oddtemp[k];
                j++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers2.length; i++) {
            if ((numbers2[i]) / 2 != 0) {
                int oddtemp[] = new int[] {};
                oddtemp[k] = numbers2[i];
                k++;
            }
        }


    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: post the code that you tried for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's like a homework and OP does not show any coding effort.

Comment: It does seem a lot like a homework, nevertheless I tried to post an answer. But intentionally made it more generic, not specific to the supplied arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bvdb's answer is good but it does not match the OP's requirement as it does not uses arrays.

Maybe not the best approach but this is what came to my mind first. Here is a complete program for the above problem.

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class test{
    public static void main(String s[]){
        int array1[] = {1,3,-5,4,2,-8};
        int array2[] = {2,4,7,8,-9};
        int array3[] = {1,2,3,-4,6};
        int count = 0;
        boolean flag = false;
        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
            int temp;
            count++;
            if(array1[i]%2==0){
                for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
                    if(array2[j]%2==1){
                        temp = array2[j];
                        array2[j] = array1[i];
                        array1[i] = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
                int temp;
                if(array1[i]%2==0){
                    for(int j=0;j<array3.length;j++){
                        if(array3[j]%2==1){
                            temp = array3[j];
                            array3[j] = array1[i];
                            array1[i] = temp;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        System.out.println("Array1");
        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Array2");
        for(int i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array2[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Array3");
        for(int i=0;i<array3.length;i++){
            System.out.println(array3[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: working good if it is pre-defined array. but i am taking array values dynamically. means array size may vary..

Comment: @pramodpatel is the number of array is fixed?

Comment: ya it is fixed. i am getting the output what i need

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that arrays have a fixed size.
**You should use a flexible collection instead** (e.g. an `ArrayList` or a `HashSet`).

Next just iterate through the arrays, and use the `add` method of the `ArrayList` class to add them to your result set.

**SPOILER WARNING:**

```
  // 2 resulting collections
  Set<Integer> oddSet = new TreeSet<>();
  Set<Integer> evenSet = new TreeSet<>();

  // the source array
  int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5};

  // iterate the array
  int element;
  for (int j = 0, jLength = array.length; j < jLength; j++)
  {
    element = array[j];
    if (element%2 == 0)
    {
      // it's even, add it to the even set
      evenSet.add(Integer.valueOf(element));
    }
    else
    {
      // it's odd, add it to the odd set
      oddSet.add(Integer.valueOf(element));
    }
  }

  // show all odds
  for (Integer oddInteger : oddSet)
  {
    System.out.println("odd integer: " + oddInteger);
  }

  // show all evens
  for (Integer evenInteger : evenSet)
  {
    System.out.println("even integer: " + evenInteger);
  }
```

Comments: a treeset is nicely sorted and only contains unique elements

It's possible to convert the sets to arrays afterwards if that's really what you want (e.g. with the `toArray` method)